# Python Github repository scrapper

Tags: python, github, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Is there any way to scrape GitHub repository and fetch code, I'm trying with one code but was not able to fetch the code from repository.

While running the below code, I was getting an empty response:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Define the target repository and file path
repo_owner = "Arbaxali"
repo_name = "Memepage-using-flask"
file_path = "memepage.py"

# Define the list of functions to fetch
functions_to_fetch = ["get_meme()", "index()"]

# Send a GET request to the repository file page
url = f"https://github.com/{repo_owner}/{repo_name}/blob/master/{file_path}"
response = requests.get(url)

# Parse the HTML content of the response
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
# Find all the code blocks in the file content
code_blocks = soup.find_all('div', class_='highlight')
print(code_blocks)

# Extract the requested functions from the code blocks
functions = {}
for code_block in code_blocks:
# Check if the code block contains a function definition
  if code_block.find('span', {'class': 'nf'}) and code_block.find('span', {'class': 
'kd'}) == 'def':
function_name = code_block.find('span', {'class': 'nf'}).text
    # Check if the function is in the list of functions to fetch
if function_name in functions_to_fetch:
  function_code = code_block.find('pre').text
  functions[function_name] = function_code
  print(functions)

# Print the extracted functions
for function_name, function_code in functions.items():
   print(f"Function Name: {function_name}\nFunction Code:\n{function_code}\n")
```

Comment: Doesn't github have an API, maybe that could be useful?

Comment: As in... `git clone ...`?

Comment: Depending on what you want to do this might be interisting. 

https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html

When you then need the complete repo afterwards `git clone ...` can be used

Comment: [GitHub API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest) should be your tool of choice. Don't scrape the repo. And if you need the code, why don't you just clone it and/or fork it and take out the bits you need?

Comment: i want to create a program where it goes and search inside the reppo and fetch functions to complete my python code kinda chatgpt but not exactly

Answer (score 1):

I made your example working (with the very specific repo you used in the snippet) using the "raw" GitHub API:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# Define the target repository and file path
repo_owner = "Arbaxali"
repo_name = "Memepage-using-flask"
file_path = "memepage.py"

# Define the list of functions to fetch
functions_to_fetch = ["get_meme()", "index()"]

# Send a GET request to the repository file page
url = f"https://raw.githubusercontent.com/{repo_owner}/{repo_name}/main/{file_path}"
print(url)
response = requests.get(url)

# Parse the HTML content of the response
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
print(soup)
# Find all the code blocks in the file content
code_blocks = soup.find_all('div', class_='highlight')
print(code_blocks)

# Extract the requested functions from the code blocks
functions = {}
for code_block in code_blocks:
# Check if the code block contains a function definition
  if code_block.find('span', {'class': 'nf'}) and code_block.find('span', {'class': 'kd'}) == 'def':
    function_name = code_block.find('span', {'class': 'nf'}).text
    # Check if the function is in the list of functions to fetch
    if function_name in functions_to_fetch:
      function_code = code_block.find('pre').text
      functions[function_name] = function_code
      print(functions)

# Print the extracted functions
for function_name, function_code in functions.items():
   print(f"Function Name: {function_name}\nFunction Code:\n{function_code}\n")
```

It returns:

```
from urllib import response
from flask import Flask, render_template
import requests
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

# @app.route("/")
# def index():
#     return "drink more coffee right now"

# app.run(host = "0.0.0.0", port=80)

def get_meme():
    url ="https://meme-api.herokuapp.com/gimme"
    response = json.loads(requests.request("GET",url).text)
    meme_large = response["preview"][-2]
    subreddit = response["subreddit"]
    return meme_large, subreddit


@app.route("/")
def index():
    meme_pic,subreddit = get_meme()
    return  render_template("meme_index.html", meme_pic=meme_pic, subreddit=subreddit)

app.run(host = "0.0.0.0", port=80)
```

Actually I don't know if this solution could be easily portable to all accounts but hopefully it may give you a direction.